# run docker command on existing container or start new container

Tags: docker

I have a container that takes too long to start. Therefore I want to keep it running.

Is there a command that does

```
if container is_running:
  # exec
  docker exec «container_name» «command»
else:
  #create, start, and exec
  docker run --name «container_name» «image_name» «command»
```

Bonus (but not needed)
`docker stop` after x hours of inactivity.

I could probably to it all in a shell script. However, the first bit seems like what docker run may be able to do.